# Python3 - Sanitizing user input for shell use

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell, input, sanitization

I am busy writing a Python3 script which requires user input, the input is used as parameters in commands passed to the shell.

The script is only intended to be used by trusted internal users - however I'd rather have some contingencies in place to ensure the valid execution of commands.

Example 1:

```
import subprocess

user_input = '/tmp/file.txt'
subprocess.Popen(['cat', user_input])
```

This will output the contents of '/tmp/file.txt'

Example 2:

```
import subprocess

user_input = '/tmp/file.txt && rm -rf /'
subprocess.Popen(['cat', user_input])
```

Results in (as expected):

```
cat: /tmp/file.txt && rm -rf /: No such file or directory
```

Is this an acceptable method of sanitizing input? Is there anything else, per best practice, I should be doing in addition to this?

Comment: No, not from a file. Input is entered via an interactive menu in the terminal. I just simplified it my question. The variable "user_input" just represents whatever the user supposedly entered into the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you have chosen,

```
import subprocess
user_input = 'string'
subprocess.Popen(['command', user_input])
```

is quite good as `command` is static and `user_input` is passed as *one single argument* to `command`. As long as you don't do something really stupid like

```
subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', user_input])
```

you should be on the safe side.

---

For commands that require multiple arguments, I'd recommend that you request *multiple inputs* from the user, e.g. do this

```
user_input1='file1.txt'
user_input2='file2.txt'
subprocess.Popen(['cp', user_input1, user_input2])
```

instead of this

```
user_input="file1.txt file2.txt"
subprocess.Popen(['cp'] + user_input.split())
```

---

If you want to increase security further, you could:

- explicitly set `shell=False` (to ensure you never run shell commands; this is already the current default, but defaults may change over time):

  ```
  subprocess.Popen(['command', user_input], shell=False)
  ```
- use absolute paths for `command` (to prevent injection of malicious executables via `PATH`):

  ```
  subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/command', user_input])
  ```
- explicitly instruct commands that support it to stop parsing options, e.g.

  ```
  subprocess.Popen(['rm', '--', user_input1, user_input2])
  ```
- do as much as you can natively, e.g. `cat /tmp/file.txt` could be accomplished with a few lines of Python code instead (which would also increase portability if that should be a factor)